# How to connect sim900a module with arduino to transmit AT commands?

Tags: gsm, arduino-uno, i2c

I hav tried connecting through serial communication. But i hav a problem with that. I think AT commands can be also given through I2C communication. But I am getting stuck at some point. Can anyone help with step by step instructions to make a connection? thank you

Comment: This sounds like a hardware related question rather than programming.

Comment: You have connected SIM900A with Arduino, Can you share how you have connected that?
SIM900A used to accept command via Serial communication with no problem. So if you share some more information about your hardware then it would be more clear to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need mainly 3 pins to connect Arduino Uno and GSM Modem.

1. RxD
2. TxD
3. GND

This [Tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Interfacing-SIM900A-GSM-Modem-with-Arduino/) will clear all your doubt about hardware connection and also about Arduino sketch you have write.